# Go build command throws - panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []uint8, not *validator.FieldValidator

Tags: go, grpc-go, protobuf-go

In below Go function I am getting error when I tried to run build command to generate pb.go file.
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []uint8, not *validator.FieldValidator
github.com/mygithub/myproject/plugin.getFieldValidatorIfAny(0xc0001d4b60, 0x5b5020)

Any suggestion on how to resolve this

```
func getFieldValidatorIfAny(field *descriptor.FieldDescriptorProto) *validator.FieldValidator {
    if field.Options != nil {
        v, err := proto.GetExtension(field.Options, validator.E_Field)
        if err == nil && v.(*validator.FieldValidator) != nil {
            return (v.(*validator.FieldValidator))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am trying to add validation using from https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://beta.pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#GetExtension (emphasis mine):

> If the descriptor is type complete (i.e., ExtensionDesc.ExtensionType is non-nil), then GetExtension parses the encoded field and returns a Go value of the specified type. If the field is not present, then the default value is returned (if one is specified), otherwise ErrMissingExtension is reported.
>
> **If the descriptor is type incomplete (i.e., ExtensionDesc.ExtensionType is nil), then GetExtension returns the raw encoded bytes for the extension field.**

So, here it appears that `validator.E_Field` is “type incomplete”. You may need to add a dependency on the package that defines the extension so that its type will be registered — perhaps by using [`import _ "example.com/some/proto"`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) to link it in to your binary.